# implementation of Spatial db with a relational dbms

Tags: mysql, spatial, database

First post here..

I want to implement some basic spatial tables, with no use of built in types (such as geometry,point,linestring)

I have to do this to implement an exercise for my university.

The proposed analysis is:

**Points** (**Point_ID**, X, Y)

**Segments** (**Segment_ID**, From_Point, To_Point)

**Polylines** (**Polyline_ID**, Segment_ID, Line_Seq_No)

**Regions** (**Region_ID**, Polyline_ID, Region_Seq_No)

Using the above i make the following tables (in mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
  `point_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`point_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polylines` (
  `polyline_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `segment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `line_seq_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`polyline_id`),
  KEY `segment_id` (`segment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regions` (
  `region_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `polyline_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region_seq_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`),
  KEY `polyline_id` (`polyline_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `segments` (
  `segment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_point` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_point` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`segment_id`),
  KEY `from_point` (`from_point`),
  KEY `to_point` (`to_point`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


ALTER TABLE `polylines`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `polylines_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`segment_id`) REFERENCES `segments` (`segment_id`);

ALTER TABLE `regions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `regions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`polyline_id`) REFERENCES `polylines` (`polyline_id`);

ALTER TABLE `segments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `segments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`to_point`) REFERENCES `points` (`point_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `segments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_point`) REFERENCES `points` (`point_id`);
```

I don't know if this above implementation is in the right approach..

I understand how to store data into **points** and **segments** table..

But i have no idea how can i store a polyline or a region.
For example, into line_seq_no what i must store? seq=>sequence, but if i store a sequence of segments how can i retrieve this segments with a query?

Thx in advance

Comment: It depends what actions you're going to want to perform on the data... efficiently searching spatial data requires structures suited to that purpose, such as R-Trees; MySQL provides indexes built upon such data structures, but only if using its spatial extensions (which you have apparently ruled out).

Comment: @eggyal i don't care about the efficiency. I will run some difficult queries such as `find the Euclidean distance between a point and a polyline` i am not searching the best solution, i just searching a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to use entity-relationship lingo in this answer.

You need two entities to store a polyline.  The first is the polyline entity, and the second is the point-along-polyline entity.  There's a one --> many relationship between polyline --> point-along-polyline.  In other words, it's helpful to think of a polyline as an ordered sequence of points in a plane, between which lines should be drawn.

For some reason you have proposed polyline --> segment as your one --> many relationship.  That's not an ideal choice for coding efficiency, because each segment's endpoint needs to be the same as the next segment's start point.

Additionally, the point-along-polyline entities need to have an ordinal attribute to allow you to order them correctly.

In MySQL lingo you need two tables for this:

Polyline:  polylineID, name,   other attributes
PointAlongPolyline:   pointID (ascending), polylineID, x, y, other attributes

To get the sequence of points in a particular polyline you might use this query:

```
 SELECT x,y
   FROM Polyline 
   JOIN PointAlongPolyLine ON Polyline.polylineID = PointAlongPolyline.polylineID
  WHERE Polyline.name = 'name you hope to retrieve'
  ORDER BY PointAlongPolyline.pointID
```

A polygon is a type of polyline that implicitly has a line segment from its last point to its first.  It seems that you are defining a region as a set of polygons. Is that correct?